# MDX Ordering By Dimension

Tags: sorting, mdx, pentaho

Over in the SQL side, my data is looking like this:

```
Select f.id, f.TimeKey,t.CalendarYearMonth 
from FactSubmission f
inner join DimTime t on t.TimeKey = f.TimeKey
order by f.Id asc
```

[image]

Sorting from MDX we have descending

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY ORDER(
 [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].Members,
 [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_KEY"), 
 DESC
 )  ON COLUMNS
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission]
```

[image]

And Ascending

[image]

The January dates aren't at the top of either sort, which suggests I'm sorting by the `FactSubmission.ID` key instead of `DimTime.CalendarYearMonth`

Is this how things are supposed to work? I'd like to pull back Jan,Feb,March.

DimTime.CalendarYearMonthNum is a column with data in the form 201501,201502,201503 etc. Here's an attempt at using this column to to sort the CalendarYearMonth data.

[image]

Debugging Query to Select Keys
[image]

NonEmpty Query
[image]

Comment: It seems to be ordering strings, which would result in such output depending on `ASC` / `DESC` order. Perhaps you could change the values to number of months eg: `2016-01` ...

Comment: @ConsiderMe I kind of see what you're saying. If I switch the first and second ORDER parameters to be strict number values the sorting works as expected. Would there be a way to select the string version, and sort by the corresponding numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

Try ordering using a different property:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY ORDER(
 [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].Members,
 [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_Value"), 
 DESC
 )  ON COLUMNS
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission];
```

or maybe this:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY ORDER(
 [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].Members,
 [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.MEMBERValue, 
 DESC
 )  ON COLUMNS
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission];
```

In the above you should be good using `DESC` - sometimes you need to break the underlying hierarchical ordering by adding a `B` i.e. `BDESC`

---

From here I cannot see `MEMBER_VALUE`: http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/mdx.php

...but there is a function `.VALUE` so maybe try the following:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY ORDER(
 [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].Members,
 [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.Value, 
 DESC
 )  ON COLUMNS
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission];
```

---

Strange that the key doesn't work. What values do you get if you run something like this?

```
WITH MEMBER [KEYcheck] AS
    [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_KEY")
    //[DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.MEMBER_KEY
    //[DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.MEMBER_KEY
    //[DimTime].CurrentMember.MEMBER_KEY
SELECT
  [KEYcheck] ON 0,
  [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].Members ON 1
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for for replying to all my MDX questions, looking at the intrinsic properties documented here (http://diethardsteiner.github.io/olap/2015/02/27/Mondrian-MDX-Intrinsic-Member-Properties.html), MEMBER_VALUE might be the same as MEMBER_KEY? MEMBER_VALUE doesn't look to be a property I can use at least. 

Consider Me had a good comment on the question about string vs. number sorting, but it doesn't seem to want to allow me to sort from a different column than the set I'm selecting.

Comment: @AndrewWalters looks like `MEMBER_VALUE` is not implemented in Modrian. Try just `.Value` instead.

Comment: It looks like using [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember.Value as the second parameter sorts the same as using the MEMBER_KEY property

Comment: @AndrewWalters as well as using the argument `DESC` did you try `BDESC`? I'm intrigued to know what values you're using in your cube for `CalendarYearMonth`.

Comment: The Bdesc, Basc behave the same way. Values should be up at the top of the question (the sql select). If that wasn't quite what you're looking for let me know.

Comment: @AndrewWalters I added a diagnostic script so we can get an idea of what is going on - try running it. We should then know what the actual values are that it is using for the ordering.

Comment: I attached an image of the exact script you dropped in, for some reason it returns nothing when executed. I gave a shot at a few tweaks to get it to run, but didn't have any luck. Any thoughts on why nothing might be coming back?

Comment: @AndrewWalters not too sure: I added a couple of other possibles to the script. It returning nothing is the reason that the ordering is not being enforced - so at least we know the reason why.

Comment: It looks like all of those queries don't pull back any data. Could there be something super beginer-level I'm doing wrong? Maybe not even query related by on the schema itself that would cause this behavior

Comment: @GregGalloway - can you help Greg as I'm at a loss as to what is happening here!!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an alphabetical sort. **F**ebruary->**J**anuary->**M**arch.

For doing a sort based on the month number, there needs to be a field which maps January-1, February-2, March-3.

If you have such a column in cube, use that to to sort. If not create a calculated member like below -

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.CalendarMonth AS
CASE [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].CurrentMember
 WHEN  [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].&[January] THEN 1
 WHEN  [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].&[February] THEN 2
 WHEN  [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].&[March] THEN 3
END

SELECT
NON EMPTY ORDER(
 [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].Members,
 Measures.CalendarMonth, 
 DESC
 )  ON COLUMNS
FROM [PSE_FactSubmission]
```

**EDIT for Andrew**

```
with member Measures.[MonthNum] as
NonEmpty
    ( 
     [DimTime.CalendarYearMonthNum].[CalendarMonthNum].members,
     ([DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].currentmember, Measures.foo)
    ).item(0).membervalue

select
non empty
order
  (
   [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].members,
   Measures.[MonthNum],
   desc
  ) on rows
from [PSE_FactSubmission]
```

**EDIT** - with `EXISTS`

```
with member Measures.[MonthNum] as
EXISTS
      (
       [DimTime.CalendarYearMonthNum].[CalendarMonthNum].members,
       [DimTime.CalendarYearMonth].[CalendarYearMonth].currentmember,
       "SomeMeasureGroup"
      ).item(0).membervalue
```

Comment: I have another field, CalendaryearMonthNum which looks like 201501, 201502, 201503 etc. 
How would I use this field to sort the CalendarYearMonth values?

Comment: Perfectly! Please use that field.

Comment: Would you be able to check out my syntax? I've updated the original question down at the bottom.

Comment: In the with statement, what is Measures.foo supposed to be?

Comment: @SouravA instead of using `NonEmpty` with a measure, because `[CalendarMonthNum]` and `[CalendarYearMonth]` are two hierarchies in the same dimension you can use the `EXISTS` function instead of `NonEmpty`: it should work nicely.

Comment: Yeah I strongly thought about `EXISTS` too. But, I am not sure if performance wise, it is better than `NonEmpty`. Secondly OP didn't mention any measure group nor told about relations between facts and dims. So for the sake of simplicity, I thought of this approach. Let OP come back with feedback and me run some performance tests.

Comment: @SouravA To me, performance is less important than learning why the sorting isn't working as I expect.

Comment: @AndrewWalters `Measures.foo` is just a placeholder - replace it with a measure from your cube.

Comment: I updated the question with what I've got. Does Measures represent the fact table?

Comment: @AndrewWalters - So Mondrian doesn't support NonEmpty too(it sucks basically). Have added another version that should work.

Comment: I feel like basic notempty is there, because I used it with a simple cross join. I can't argue with Mondrian sucking though based on this experience trying to do a sort.